# Can I use Visual Studio Community 2015 without .NET?

Tags: visual-studio, html-editor

I'm looking for a new html/jquery/css IDE to edit and publish existing websites. Can I use Visual Studio Community 2015 to edit a website that doesn't use .NET and publish it to a server using ftp?

Comment: Yes - Visual Studio will provide a project that enables you to build .NET components, but you can choose to write only client side components, i.e., HTML, jQuery or CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Visual Studio as your main editor. Select any ASP.NET project as your starting point, delete everything in the project and you're good to go. You can add a Publish Profile to enable web deployment (which supports FTP).

It will require the concept of a "Project File" for most features to work well. There is the old Web Site project which just works on any folder, but that hasn't seen much love in the past years. [It's new cousin is being introduced with Visual Studio 15](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/04/12/open-any-folder-with-visual-studio-15-preview/) (which will likely be Visual Studio 2016 or 2017).

As an alternative you may want to look at [Visual Studio Code as well](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx), it's the light weight cousin of Visual Studio Community Edition and is suited perfectly for the kind of work you're planning it seems.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I tried creating an asp.net project, but got bogged down deleting the 50 megs of extra stuff. I'm impatient, I guess. I'll probably try VS 2016-17 when it supports the Project File concept. Visual Studio Code gets VERY close to what I need. It lacks a few key features (e.g., search/replace across files, better ftp support), but seeing as it was release last month, it looks very promising.